# Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib, using Anaconda on OS X

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am unable to use the MKL-enabled version of NumPy on OS X (10.11.3). The modules seem to install OK, but when I try to import it I get the error `Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../../libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib`. Indeed, if I search for this file (`mdfind -name libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib`) nothing is returned. Is this a problem with the package or my install? The same process works flawlessly on my Windows machine. I am able to install the `nomkl` build and import it without any difficulty, but I'd like to use MKL if it's available.

*Edit*: Installing the dylibs manually from the mkl package (http://anaconda.org/anaconda/mkl/files) seems to work - perhaps this is a bug?

*Installing NumPy*:

```
snorfmac-2:~ snorf$ source activate snowflake
discarding /Users/snorf/miniconda3/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/bin to PATH
(snowflake)snorfmac-2:~ snorf$ conda install numpy
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .............
Package plan for installation in environment /Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    mkl:   11.3.1-0     
    numpy: 1.10.4-py34_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? 

Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|###################################################| 100%
```

*Attemping to import the module*:

```
(snowflake)snorfmac-2:~ snorf$ python
Python 3.4.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jan  9 2016, 17:30:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 184, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 10): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../../libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/snowflake/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Did you add the needed extra stuff for MKL? It isn't a free software. License info etc. http://docs.continuum.io/mkl-optimizations/index

Comment: I hadn't appreciated the licence restrictions. How can I get conda to install the `nomkl` package when running `conda build` when it isn't specified in `meta.yaml`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like for some reason the `mkl` package was installed the archive wasn't extracted fully. Subsequent installations were using this incomplete extraction. This was reported when running `conda install --debug mkl`:

```
DEBUG:conda.install:pkgs_dir='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs', prefix='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34', dist='mkl-11.3.1-0', linktype=1
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_avx512.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_avx512.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_core.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_core.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_intel.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_intel.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_intel_ilp64.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_intel_ilp64.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_mc.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_mc.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_mc3.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_mc3.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_rt.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_rt.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_sequential.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_sequential.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_vml_avx.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_vml_avx.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_vml_avx2.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_vml_avx2.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_vml_avx512.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_vml_avx512.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_vml_mc.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_vml_mc.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_vml_mc2.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_vml_mc2.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
ERROR:conda.install:failed to link (src='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/pkgs/mkl-11.3.1-0/lib/libmkl_vml_mc3.dylib', dst='/Users/snorf/miniconda3/envs/python34/lib/libmkl_vml_mc3.dylib', type=1, error=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Deleting the offending directory and reinstalling the `mkl` package fixed things.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! I was getting a similar error because I was using MKL in a Keras/Tensorflow application.